# Angular.Не появляется значение в input при тесте

Tags: angular2, angular5, angular

Код теста:

```
  it('should select hero on click', () => {
        const expectedHero = HEROES[1];
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeroesComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
        compiled.querySelectorAll('li')[1].click();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(expectedHero.name).toEqual(compiled.querySelector('input').value);
      });
```

При тесте в inpute не появляется выбранное имя
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class='heroes'>
  <li *ngFor='let hero of heroes'
  [class.selected]='hero === selectedHero'
  (click)='onSelect(hero)'>
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

<div *ngIf='selectedHero'>

  <h2>{{ selectedHero.name | uppercase }} Details</h2>
  <div><span>id: </span>{{ selectedHero.id }}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name:
      <input [(ngModel)]='selectedHero.name' placeholder='name'>
    </label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Весь код из Tour of Hero с сайта Angular.io

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HEROES } from '../mock-heroes';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes = HEROES;

  selectedHero: Hero;

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HeroesComponent ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Comment: могу скинуть всю папку с приложением

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема в том, что эти тесты асинхронные, поэтому нужно дождаться момента, когда выполнятся колбеки асинхронных тасков, в данном случае `onSelect` выполнится после `fixture.detectChanges`, но `whenStable` позволяет нам выполнить определенные тесты после того, как очередь зоны (`zone.js`) со всеми тасками (`eventTask | macroTask | microTask`) пуста:

```
it('should select hero on click', () => {
    const expectedHero = HEROES[1];
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    compiled.querySelectorAll('li')[1].click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(expectedHero.name).toEqual(compiled.querySelector('input').value);
    });
});
```

Также добавьте `FormsModule` в окружение тестового модуля:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule
    ]
});
```

Comment: у меня все равно не работает. И тут должно быть AppComponent a не HeroesComonent(const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);)

Comment: Это неважно, я просто не создавал у себя `HeroesComponent`, а засунул все в `App`, поменяйте название и все

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/D1mrVhk

Comment: и покажите как вы конфигурируете тестовый модуль через `TestBed.configureTestingModule`

Comment: я удалил второй fixture.detectChanges и заработало

Comment: beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HeroesComponent ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

Comment: compiled.querySelectorAll('li')[1].click(); если изменяю на другое чилсо все равно правильно